# jq using stream to parse a json file > 20 gb

Tags: json, stream, jq

i have a json file which is >20 gb of data like below:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$serialnumber": "572"
  },
  "content": "{\"001\":\"77\",\"401\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$serialnumber": "573"
  },
  "content": "{\"001\":\"234\",\"424\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$serialnumber": "574"
  },
  "content": "{\"001\":\"549\",\"432\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$serialnumber": "575"
  },
  "content": "{\"001\":\"888\",\"532\":[[\" 0\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"Euy/ O\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"],[\"g\",\"R2\"]],[\" 1\",[\"a\",\"UK\"],[\"b\",\"LO\"],[\"c\",\"20160811\"]]]}"
}
```

i need a way with jq stream (i have installed version 1.6) to get all 001 values, that have in the content, a 4.. element.(400, or 401, or 402, or 403, ...)

for example the above would return:

```
77
234
549
```

and not 888, which does not contain any 4.. element.

```
001 77 has the \"401\" element
001 234 has the \"424\" element
001 549 has the \"432\" element
```

below please find one of my attempts to solve this:

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][] == "_id") | del(.[0][0]))) | select(.content == "400")'
```

Comment: Why do you use `--stream`? Do you see an error without it?

Comment: i use the stream option, since i have a json file which is more than 20 gigabyte size

Comment: Yeah but your input seem to be a *stream* of objects itself. I thought such an input shouldn't cause a memory error, am I wrong?

Comment: could you please elaborate with an example on how i should change the jq command, so as not get errors, since even without the stream option i get no valid result

Comment: Like, if your input is not an array but a stream like shown in the question, `.content|fromjson|select(keys[1]|startswith("4")) ."001"` should work imo

Comment: perhaps i am missing something. i get errors with the above, i think somehow i must change it appropriately

Comment: Maybe it's me. But I think you should provide a truly representative example and the errors you get in order for us to help. Btw the script I posted above is supposed be used without any options to jq

Comment: on jq play, it works. But when i give jq .content|fromjson|select(keys[1]|startswith("4")) ."001" my.json i get
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: surround it with single quotes. Like `jq '...' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is already a stream, there is no need to use the --stream option.  The following produces the desired output:

```
< input.json jq -r '.content
| fromjson
| select( any(keys_unsorted[]; test("^4")) )
| .["001"]'
```